# Why does Kali Linux have other existing users from /etc/passwd file? I never created these users

Tags: kali-linux, passwd, etc, file-format

I simply wanted to see my user that I just created in the terminal but I came across this sea of users in my existing Kali Linux vm. The command I used displayed a list of users. It started with "root" (me) and ended with "Homer" (the user I just created). The list is extensive and includes users such as "root, Daemon, nobody, tss, king-phisher, systemd-coredump, rtkit, sshd, stunnel4, mysql, Homer." I understand that each entry with a User ID (UID's) from 1 - 99 and 100 - 999 are reserved for predefined accounts and reserved by sys administrative groups. However, a few are users with encrypted passwords and their User Id (UID) is 1000+ with a command shell of /bin/bash and /sbin/nologin. I referred to this blog: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/understanding-etcpasswd-file-format/

A newbie here so I'm probably not asking it the best way possible. But, I would like to know why these accounts exist and if they are somehow influenced when I downloaded Kali (predetermined)? Specifically, the entry with user "nobody" and "corrkid" seemed too suspicious. I will post their entry below with root (me) and Homer (user I created) for comparison.

I opened the list in Kali with:

```
root@kali:~# cat /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
nobody:x:65534:65534:nobody:/nonexistent:/usr/sbin/nologin
redsocks:x:109:114::/var/run/redsocks:/usr/sbin/nologin
rwhod:x:110:65534::/var/spool/rwho:/usr/sbin/nologin
iodine:x:111:65534::/var/run/iodine:/usr/sbin/nologin
miredo:x:112:65534::/var/run/miredo:/usr/sbin/nologin
corrkid:x:1000:1000:corrkid,,,:/home/corrkid:/bin/bash
Homer:x:1001:1001::/home/Homer:/bin/sh
```

My version of Kali Linux is (This might be useful information?):

```
# Kali GNU/Linux Rolling 
Version: "2020.3"
ID_LIKE=debian
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Half of those are NSA

Comment: What do you mean by "_too sus_"? I've not come across this phrase

Comment: @roaima sus is an abbreviation for "suspicious" read *"Specifically the entry with user "nobody" and "corrkid" seemed suspicious"*

Comment: Thank you @PhilipCouling. Never heard that one before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default contents of `/etc/passwd` in Kali are inherited [from Debian](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/base-passwd/-/blob/master/passwd.master), and you’ll see `root` and `nobody` defined there along with a few other accounts.

The accounts with ids just above 100 correspond to system users created by packages, *e.g.* [`redsocks`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/redsocks) or [`miredo`](http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/miredo).

The only suspicious accounts are `corrkid` and `Homer`. Given its id (1000), `corrkid` is the account created during installation, in these two screens:

[image: Kali user account creation, step 1 (full name of the user)]

[image: Kali user account creation, step 2 (username)]

`Homer` as you mention is the user you just created, with a somewhat unusual setup involving `/bin/sh` rather than `/bin/bash`.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks